# How to scrape new YouTube videos from a specific channel first?

Tags: web-scraping, youtube

I have a channel and I want to get a new uploaded video from it as fast as possible. What would be the best method to do it? Two option I know:

1. Use the YouTube API
2. Access the channel via url directly

With option 1 I would need to call the api in order to get a list of videos. Since there quotas in place, I guess I will run out of api calls I can make. I would assume that option 2 is the best bet, since I can call the url as often as I want.

Are new videos available via the api first? Or is a video accessed via url made available at different times to the users, depending on the region they are coming from? I build an url scraper myself. I access the url every minute. Still there are people having the video 8 minutes before I have it. I do not get why this is the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to build off a little of what MadRay wrote you can do some simple string substitution with this URL

Using Channel ID:

```
"https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=UCXuqSBlHAE6Xw-yeJA0Tunw"
```

Using Channel Name:

```
https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?user=LinusTechTips
```

Took the liberty of parsing it for you.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url="https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?user=LinusTechTips"
html = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "lxml")

for entry in soup.find_all("entry"):
    for title in entry.find_all("title"):
        print(title.text)
    for link in entry.find_all("link"):
        print(link["href"])
    for name in entry.find_all("name"):
        print(name.text)
    for pub in entry.find_all("published"):
        print(pub.text)
```

Response:

```
FINALLY Wireless Headphones that Sound GREAT
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rei5vMQmD4Q
Linus Tech Tips
2020-01-30T20:04:37+00:00
Don't give Apple your MONEY - Mac Pro Upgrade Adventure
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zcLbSCinX3U
Linus Tech Tips
2020-01-29T19:59:56+00:00
We got the Kick-Proof TV from China!
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4eSADWuZskk
Linus Tech Tips
2020-01-28T19:46:09+00:00
Everything went wrong... Water Cooled 8K Camera Final Test
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OEUCNh5g-2I
Linus Tech Tips
2020-01-27T20:08:27+00:00
I'm Returning my Mac Pro
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mIB389tqzCI
Linus Tech Tips
2020-01-26T19:59:45+00:00
The RGB HDMI cable ISN'T as dumb as you'd think...
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nva6oPszm60
Linus Tech Tips
2020-01-25T20:06:23+00:00
I am NOT Retiring... yet - WAN Show Jan 24, 2020
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cxjhTVR_dJw
Linus Tech Tips
2020-01-25T02:29:50+00:00
The Best VR Headset... got BETTER!?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AGScX_8plYw
Linus Tech Tips
2020-01-23T19:52:00+00:00
I've been thinking of retiring.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hAsZCTL__lo
Linus Tech Tips
2020-01-23T06:35:25+00:00
It’s time to upgrade your GPU - RX 5600 XT
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rKn-vWDMkwQ
Linus Tech Tips
2020-01-22T19:59:36+00:00
WE FINALLY DID IT!! - Water Cooling the 8K Camera!
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=imJ9QgOJHzY
Linus Tech Tips
2020-01-21T19:59:47+00:00
We Water Cooled an SSD!!
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lQmI5A27Iv8
Linus Tech Tips
2020-01-20T20:17:22+00:00
Should you buy a $50 CPU??
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JISJ_YTI9s0
Linus Tech Tips
2020-01-19T20:19:02+00:00
Apple’s Pro Display XDR – A PC Guy’s Perspective
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X089oYPc5Pg
Linus Tech Tips
2020-01-18T19:59:29+00:00
The NSA is Giving Out It's Hacks for Free! - WAN Show Jan 17, 2020
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=af6FBA-n7eA
Linus Tech Tips
2020-01-18T03:00:04+00:00
```

However, please keep in mind to use headers with your requests and watch out for hitting YouTube's backend too many times at once because your IP will receive a temporary 12hr suspension. Best of luck!

Comment: What is considered as "too much"? Is once a minute fine?

Comment: Once a minute is plenty enough. I want to say something around 12 to16 requests a second is what will get you pinched. Now when you're starting out that seems like more than enough, but when you're doing some heavy data harvesting you have to get creative with rotating proxies. Have fun web scraping!

Answer (score 1):

You can try RSS feed for interested channel. It contains fresh videos with UTC timestamp (so there're no issues with timezones you mentioned).

RSS link for channel's videos can be found at source of channel's page. Open source of page and search for "rssUrl":