# Scraping New YouTube Videos With BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, youtube

I'm new to python and I'm wanting to get into web scraping on YouTube.
I'm wanting to use this link to get the newest videos uploaded: 'https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=programming&sp=CAISBAgBEAE%253D' and I want to scrape the new 5 videos. How can I do this?
I've used this piece of code to test it (I only want the links) from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59724101/how-to-scrape-new-youtube-videos-from-a-specific-channel-first)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url="https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=programming&sp=CAISBAgBEAE%253D"
html = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, features="html.parser") 

for entry in soup.find_all("entry"):
    for link in entry.find_all("link"):
        print(link["href"])
```

Edit: I don't get any response from the python terminal. It's not scraping anything. It only has the default ">>>".

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) should include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it *as formatted text* (not images) **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [mre].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot scrape YouTube without using Googles YouTube API key which you can get by doing [these steps](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started). I can repost a legit answer to your question if you're still down to try.

In the mean time, try practicing your parsing with beautifulsoup on this website [videvo.net](http://videvo.net)

Here's some code to help you get started

```
def get_source(url):
    return BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"}, verify=False).text, 'html.parser')

soup = get_source('http://videvo.net')

for tags in soup.find_all('a'):
   print(tags['href'])
```

**EDIT**
I stand corrected (slightly). Youtube's main url cannot be parsed. You can try this code

```
def get_source(url):
    return BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"}, verify=False).text, 'html.parser')

soup = get_source('https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?user=kinagrannis')

for entry in soup.find_all("entry"):
   for title in entry.find_all("title"):
      print(title.text)
   for link in entry.find_all("link"):
      print(link["href"])
   for name in entry.find_all("name"):
      print(name.text)
   for pub in entry.find_all("published"):
      print(pub.text)
```

**note:** you can put any user name instead of 'kinnagrannis', user=**[username]**

Comment: I think your main issue was with not passing headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"} as your headers. This just helps get through some scraping barriers.

Answer (score 4):

You can scrape YouTube by:

- using `requests-HTML`, `playwright` or `selenium` libraries.
- using regular expression.
- using  YouTube Search Engine Results API from [SerpApi](https://serpapi.com/).

Code (it's really basic just to give an idea)

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

session = HTMLSession()
url = "https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=programming&sp=CAISBAgBEAE%253D"
response = session.get(url)
response.html.render(sleep=1, keep_page = True, scrolldown = 2)

for links in response.html.find('a#video-title'):
    link = next(iter(links.absolute_links))
    print(link)
```

Output:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OUnxJk3Bphk
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vWvtt1ESNeY
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b8OIZu5y_Ak
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xp3fHaT2_VE
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e9toQAcjOrw
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=em0Is0nyaXA
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N5JVTUAGmAM
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a0hQG-UdhYc
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SmQFxQ1fa2o
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uuMS1FYLgWQ
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8WJ-zSE32ZY
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c5MtH-xDspg
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Xktqz6VUTU
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wbo6j_iq2XY
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8eu9nliySO4
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j28PjOy_uk8
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fM2Ordt8Q9E
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tFSkaIVyNno
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1hDXlc2C3Rw
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vH9_Eo7VW3c
```

---

Using `regex` without a headless browser.

You need to reach the `var ytInitialData` element and then `"commandMetadata"` where you'll find a URL for the video `{"url":"/watch?v=Ae2TRkpjRCc",....`

Here's a starting point where it grabs all inside `var ytInitialData` on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/TkTabd/1/).

---

Alternatively, you can use [YouTube Search Engine Results API](https://serpapi.com/youtube-search-api) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan. Check out the [Playground](https://serpapi.com/playground?engine=youtube&search_query=programming&sp=CAISBAgBEAE%25253D).

Code to integrate:

```
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
  "engine": "youtube",
  "search_query": "programming",
  "sp": "CAISBAgBEAE%253D",
  "api_key": "your_secret_api_key"
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

for link in results['video_results']:
    print(f"Title: {link['title']}\nLink: {link['link']}\n")
```

Output:

```
Title: CLASS VIII BASIC HTML TAGS AND PROGRAMMING 15 4 101`
Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KIPp63tXKpU

Title: For loop in c programming #bssdlectureclasses
Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nfRN0x9VvQc

Title: [C#] Programming NatsukiBot
Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=chnigx-ezwg

Title: CS201 Short Lecture - 03 | VU Short Lecture | Introduction to Programming in (Urdu / Hindi)
Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qoxXJchd7N4

Title: Programming in C Language - While statement
Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cl0OpNCdF5I

Title: Introduction to html and Basic programming
Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A4We3NGqxuA

Title: Use of Printf & Scanf functions | Part 7 | C Programming | PadhoChalo
Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=578xS-Ugc2c

Title: C++ course has started | Computer Programming | Aashu |
Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SjFgTK2HqbE

Title: Mitsubishi Outlander 2008 prox/twist transponder key programming tip
Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HlSJcBwxKFQ

Title: Computer Programming 1 -Introduction to the course
Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xdmPbhTT01g

Title: Programming, Data Structures and Algorithms in Python
Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0fUddu9cdAU
```

P.S - I wrote two blog posts about how to [Scrape YouTube Search with Python (part 1)](https://dev.to/dimitryzub/scrape-youtube-search-with-python-part-1-j12) and [Scrape YouTube Search with Python (part 2)](https://dev.to/dimitryzub/scrape-youtube-search-with-python-part-2-29jc) that cover it more in-depth with visual representation.

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.